# Save BMP contained in SVG with reasonable filename

Tags: javascript, svg, cross-browser

I have an SVG file that contains a BMP inside an svg:image as data URI. The problem is that some browsers will not honour the `download="download.bmp"` attribute of the `svg:a` link.

```
<svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    onload="dd();" baseProfile="full" version="1.1" height="409.6" width="1036.8">
  <script type="text/ecmascript">
function dd() {
fetch(document.getElementById('thebmp').getAttribute('xlink:href')).
  then(res =&gt; res.blob()).then(res =&gt; window.URL.createObjectURL(res)).
    then(function(x) 
    { document.getElementById('theanchor').setAttribute('href', x);});
}
  </script>
  <g transform="scale(0.2)">
    <a href="#" download="download.bmp" id="theanchor">
      <image id="thebmp" height="2048" width="2592" y="0" x="163" 
        xlink:href="data:image/x-ms-bmp;base64,...."/>
    </a>
    <g transform="translate(163,0)">
      <g id="P_1_1">
        <path d="M 130 102 l 2332 0 l 0 1844 l -2332 0 l 0 -1844" style="fill:none; 
         stroke:#66ff66; stroke-width:6px; stroke-opacity:0.75;"/>
        <text y="379" x="107" font-size="75px" fill="#66ff66" text-anchor="end">[0]</text>
      </g>
    </g>
    <g transform="translate(3110,122)">
      <g transform="scale(122)">
        <text fill="#66ff66" y="0" x="0" font-size="0.9px">blah</text>
      </g>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

You can find a complete version as `testsvgf.svg` in https://www.magentacloud.de/share/6x.svy3pz9.

I want the user to be able to save the BMP image as BMP file (the original contents of the `svg:img xlink:href` and ideally propose a reasonable filename to the user.

As written, the code works only on firefox (tested 60 and 68) prompting to save with a default name of `download.bmp`.

Other browsers behave different...

Chrome proposes/saves *some-cryptic-filename-without-extension* (version 80)

Edge: does nothing on click. When selecting `Save link as` from the context menu then the filename for the download is increased starting from `(1).txt` (I could live with the context menu)

The contents of saved files is completely correct from all three browsers. Just that from Chrome and Edge, you don't recognize what you saved.

Adding e.g. `document.getElementById('theanchor').setAttribute('download', 'another.bmp*);` after `document.getElementById('theanchor').setAttribute('href', x);` does not help

What am I doing wrong? - Thanks in advance!

Comment: why don't you put your JS outside SVG ?

Comment: I just want to have that one svg file that should be self-contained (it might be an attachment itself) - would putting the JS outside make a difference on the problem?

Comment: I am not sure, but it seems to me that webKit browsers abandon the interpretation of the js code present in the svg

Comment: If that would be true, they would not save the image at all, because the href is set to the blob in the onload dd function.

Comment: without browser and any suggested filename : `xmllint  -xpath './/*[local-name() = '\''image'\'']/@*[local-name() = '\'href\'']' testsvgf.svg | sed 's@^.*data:image/x-ms-bmp;base64,@@g' |openssl base64 -d -A > some.bmp`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a foreignObject and a HTML anchor element which in Chrome does support the download attribute.

We forward the click event from the SVG anchor to the HTML anchor and it's that HTML anchor where the download actually happens.

```html
<svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    onload="dd();" baseProfile="full" version="1.1" height="409.6" width="1036.8">
  <script type="text/ecmascript">
function dd() {
fetch(document.getElementById('thebmp').getAttribute('xlink:href')).
  then(res =&gt; res.blob()).then(res =&gt; window.URL.createObjectURL(res)).
    then(function(x) 
    { document.getElementById('theanchor').setAttribute('href', x);});
}
  </script>
  <g transform="scale(0.2)">
    <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('theanchor').click()" download="download.bmp">
      <image id="thebmp" height="2048" width="2592" y="0" x="163" 
        xlink:href="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAQAMQAAORHHOVSKudfOulrSOp3WOyDZu6QdvCchPGolfO0o/XBs/fNwfjZ0frl3/zy7////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAkAABAALAAAAAAQABAAAAVVICSOZGlCQAosJ6mu7fiyZeKqNKToQGDsM8hBADgUXoGAiqhSvp5QAnQKGIgUhwFUYLCVDFCrKUE1lBavAViFIDlTImbKC5Gm2hB0SlBCBMQiB0UjIQA7"/>
    </a>
    <foreignObject width="0" height="0">
        <a xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" download="download.bmp" id="theanchor"/>
    </foreignObject>
    <g transform="translate(163,0)">
      <g id="P_1_1">
        <path d="M 130 102 l 2332 0 l 0 1844 l -2332 0 l 0 -1844" style="fill:none; 
         stroke:#66ff66; stroke-width:6px; stroke-opacity:0.75;"/>
        <text y="379" x="107" font-size="75px" fill="#66ff66" text-anchor="end">[0]</text>
      </g>
    </g>
    <g transform="translate(3110,122)">
      <g transform="scale(122)">
        <text fill="#66ff66" y="0" x="0" font-size="0.9px">blah</text>
      </g>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Okay. Really appreciate. But - cant get it to work. It works in the so snippet, but when I try to include it in my svg, it won't (either nothing will happen - i.e. appends the # to the url, or it will say 'document.getElementById(..).click()' is not a function. I'm going on to try

Comment: Please download the testsvgzzzz.svg from the magentacloud to your disk and try find the error

Comment: @RobertLongson good find! It didn't work for me until I added XHTML namespace to the tag. Editing your answer to add it in

Comment: Without the attribute, I see `document.getElementById(...).click is not a function`. With `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"`, it works.

Comment: Absolutely awsome. Sorry I probably can't split the bounty between Robert Longson for the idea and Codebling for making it work.Adding a `return false;` after the click() perfects the thing, but that's exactly 100% what I was looking for. Many many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You're not doing anything wrong!

The `download` attribute is officially supported in the [Scalable Vector Graphics (SVG) 2 *draft*](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/linking.html#AElementDownloadAttribute). Unfortunately, it's a *draft*. Like many other web technologies, the official specifications don't always move fast enough (SVG 1.1 was published in 2011), and many browsers are keen to adopt specs early.

This is exactly why [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/) exists. Incidentally, it shows that the svg:a element's `download` attribute is [currently only supported by Firefox](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-svg_elements_a_download).

You could file a feature request for the browsers that don't support it yet, or wait a few <s>weeks</s> years until it's supported everywhere.

FYI the `download` attribute was [added in June 2016](https://github.com/w3c/svgwg/commit/33f85d2bdd20e7d33eedff77b85b10c8451db397#diff-6e6915b15fe92e713aecbcc7786991f6R20)

Thanks for showing a weird example of what you can do with SVG!

Comment: Not that I know of! I tried a few things but couldn't get anything to work.

Comment: Any experience with the `foreignObject` suggested by Robert Longson?

Comment: @StefanHegny I hadn't but checked it out. Edited his answer, it was missing an attribute